# Window moving by clicking on Button

Tags: java, window

I am learning Java development and my teacher gave me an exercise to create a window with four Buttons for moving the window up, down, right, or left in 10px steps. I wrote this source:

```
if (e.getActionCommand().equals("right")){
if(getX() < Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getWidth()-getSize().getWidth())
setLocation(getX() + 10, getY());
}

if (e.getActionCommand().equals("left")){
if(getX() > 0)
setLocation(getX() - 10, getY());
}

if (e.getActionCommand().equals("up")){
if(getY() > 0)
setLocation(getX(), getY() - 10);
}

if (e.getActionCommand().equals("down")){
if(getY() < Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getHeight()-getSize().getHeight())
setLocation(getX(), getY() + 10);
}
if(e.getActionCommand().equals("ende"))
System.exit(0);
```

My teacher told me this source has three problems, but I have no idea what they are. Do you have some hints on how to improve it?

Comment: When posting any question on this site, please state what efforts you have taken to answer your own question.  For example, you never mentioned if you tried to execute your code and if so, what the result was.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the buttons to either add or subtract 10 from the X and Y coordinates, and checking to see if the values are within the range of the screen size, but not taking into account that you are changing them 10 units at a time.
Think about what happens when getX() returns a number from 1 to 9 and you click the "left" button, where will your new X coordinate be?

Comment: Thats what I have thought too, but when I Test it the window keepy inside the screensize. I don´t why because its logical impossible

Comment: The window manager may limit the values, or the window may be starting off on multiples of 10, but I think the latter would still let it go off the right and bottom of the screen by 10 pixels. It may 'work' letting the values go under/over, but your instructor might want you to handle that situation anyway . I would ask them if that's what they think the problem is. 
I would always make sure values don't go out of bounds in my own code rather than relying on someone else's code down the line taking care of it.